# JavaScriptMVC: How to use model findAll to encapsulate these URLs?

Tags: javascript, javascriptmvc, canjs, canjs-model

I have following URLs:

```
/tasks/             // Return a list of JSON
/task/next-week/    // Return a list of JSON
```

I have Task model in JSMVC:

```
$.Model('Task', {

    findAll: 'GET /tasks/',
    findOne: 'GET /task/{id}'

});
```

How can I support `/task/next-week/` ?

The following code:

```
Task.findAll({'range': 'next-week'})
```

results in the request `/tasks/?range=next-week`, but this is wrong for my project.

How could I properly encapsulate the service, so the request will look normally like `/task/next-week/`?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a function for `findAll` and make a custom ajax request, such as what's suggested in [the docs](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!jQuery.Model.static.findAll):

```
$.Model('Task', {

    findAll: function(params, success, error){

        if (!params.range) params.range = '';

        return $.ajax({
            url: '/tasks/' + params.range,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json task.models',
            success: success,
            error: error
        });
    },

    findOne: 'GET /task/{id}'

});
```